# executing upgrade grub failed this is a fatal error

Tags: 20.04, system-installation

While installing Ubuntu 20.04 from a live usb, the following error is displayed:
`executing upgrade grub failed this is a fatal error`

Please help.

Comment: Is it the same computer as your other question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359585/ubuntu-21-04-booting-error If it is then why are you posting another question without checking the drive? It's very likely the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes. I expressed my apology on the other post. I am looking into it.

Comment: The drive is defective. Replace it is what you should do, not post vague questions. The other one at least showed a quite evident "I/O error" on sda .

Comment: You are suggesting replacing my current hard drive with a brand new one?

Comment: It doesn't have to be "brand new". Any known good drive, i.e. tested and found to be working (no bad sectors, etc.), regardless of age or prior usage, will do.

Comment: I suggesting asking the drive itself about your drive's health, ie. using it's onboard capacity for *Self-Monitoring, Analysis & Reporting Technology* (SMART) contained on the circuit board of almost all drives. It's very possible it'll tell you you're just wasting time until you replace it if it's defective.

Comment: I replaced the HDD with a SSD. The computer is working smoothly now.